# Synch call on willFinishLaunchingWithOptions (AppDelegate)

Tags: ios, splash-screen, appdelegate

I would to do a remote call before the app is started (in AppDelegate, when the splash screen is showed). Then i would to choose which view controller to load based on url response.
Is right to do this on AppDelegate? Or I need a different approach?

Comment: If it doesn't take too long I think its fine otherwise users will think your app crashed and might as well close it. Ideally long processing should be done in ViewController with a UIActivity circle showing that your app is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best approach is creating a ViewController where you make this choice. Once this VC is loaded you make your remote call while showing in the UI that your app is actually working and waiting for a network response - the best approach is probably showing a message with a UIActivityIndicatorView spinning.

Once you get the response you load the VC that you need. You should also handle errors - what are you going to show if the network request fails? Are you showing an error message?

Comment: No, if the network request fails I go on with the default view controller. If it responds correctly I have to choose between the default VC or another VC.

Comment: As @Duncan C confirmed - I would proceed creating a "loading" VC where you make the call and then you load the other VC you need accordingly.

Comment: I think you're right, because if the request takes too much time the app will crash. For the other hand I think that if the response is very fast the UIActivityIndicatorView should be shown for a very little time (I think it will seem rough!).

Comment: I think it's alright showing the UIActivityIndicator even for a very short time - it's actually very common in some situations. But I'll leave the UI design to you :) Good luck. Ciao!

Answer (score 2):

You should not do any synchronous network calls from willFinishLaunchingWithOptions. If you take more than a few seconds to return that method or (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, or the other app delegate methods that the system calls in the process of launching your app) then the springboard will terminate your app as unresponsive.

@Tanzolone has the right idea. Have your app display a view controller that shows your app's UI, THEN invoke the network request and decide what second screen to switch to based on the response.